# What is the equivalent to $? in Windows?

Tags: windows, linux, command-line

Does anybody know what is the equivalent to **`$?`** in Windows command line? Is there any?

*EDIT:* `$?` is the UNIX variable which holds the exit code of the last process

Comment: Question doesn't make sense without some context

Comment: Shouldn't you tag this for Windows?

Comment: He's talking about the Unix shell variable that holds the last process's exit code.

Comment: are you referring to finding the logged in user?

Comment: @Duck: Sorry I'm having issues with keyboard so I sent it accidentally with some wrong TAB+ENTER combinations when trying to selectit from the suggestion list. @birdlips: No, I'm not. Just updated the question

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You want to check the value of [`%ERRORLEVEL%`](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/errorlevel.php).

Answer (score 11):

### Windows Batch Files

> %ERRORLEVEL% Returns the error code of
>   the most recently used command. A non
>   zero value usually indicates an error.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490954.aspx

### Windows Powershell

> $?
>     Contains True if last operation succeeded and False otherwise. And
>
> $LASTEXITCODE
>     Contains the exit code of the last Win32 executable execution.

http://blogs.msdn.com/powershell/archive/2006/09/15/ErrorLevel-equivalent.aspx

### Cygwin Bash Scripting

> $? Expands to the exit status code of
>   the most recently executed foreground
>   program.

http://unix.sjcc.edu/cis157/BashParameters.htm

Answer (score 3):

Sorry to dredge up an old thread, but it's worth noting that %ERRORLEVEL% doesn't get reset with *every* command.  You can still test "positive" for errorlevel after several lines of subsequent--and successful--batch code.

You can reliably reset errorlevel to a clean status with `ver`.  This example works with UnxUtils for a more Linux-ish directory listing.  The reset might seem extraneous at the end, but not if I need to call this script from another.

```
:------------------------------------------------------------------------------
:  ll.bat - batch doing its best to emulate UNIX
:  Using UnxUtils when available, it's nearly unix.
:------------------------------------------------------------------------------
:  ll.bat - long list: batch doing its best to emulate UNIX
:  ------------------------------------
:  zedmelon, designer, 2005 | freeware
:------------------------------------------------------------------------------
@echo off
    setlocal
    : use the UnxUtil ls.exe if it is in the path
    ls.exe -laF %1 2>nul

if errorlevel 1 (
    echo.
    echo ----- ls, DOS-style, as no ls.exe was found in the path -----
    echo.
    dir /q %1
    )

: reset errorlevel
    ver>nul 
    endlocal
```

Feel free to use this.  If you haven't seen UnxUtils, check 'em out.

Answer (score 1):

```
@echo off
run_some_command
if errorlevel 2 goto this
if errorlevel 1 goto that
goto end

:this
echo This
goto end

:that
echo That
goto end

:end
```

Comment: Beware that the "if errorlevel" operation tests if the errorlevel variable is equal to *or* greater than the given number. So if you need to test for more than one possible value, the numbers must be checked in decreasing order (as shown in the example).

Answer (score 0):

%errorlevel%