# "Error: Command failed: ..." when I execute commands with exec / execSync

Tags: node.js, child-process

```
const {execSync , exec} = require('child_process')
const res = execSync("help")
console.log(res.toString())
```

For every command I try to execute (in this case 'help') it throws the error "Error: Command Failed .... not found". What I do not understand?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Dive in NodeJs child process module

I decided to look at NodeJS source code at [here](https://github1s.com/nodejs/node/blob/HEAD/lib/child_process.js) to understand the problem. `execSync` method use `spawnSync` to run the command, and in the end, it calls `checkExecSyncError`. In the latter, you can see that if the status code is not 0, it will throw the error "Command failed ...".

Then I try to run `const res = spawnSync("help");`, and `res.status` gives me 1. So,  the command `help` actually yields an "invisible" error although we can see the expected output on the terminal.

*Note*: Exit status 1 is the catch-all for general error, AFAIK. Exit status 0 means success. [Further reading](https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/exit-codes-demystified)

#### Confirm in the terminal

I go to my terminal to confirm this, I ran `help` then `echo %ERRORLEVEL%.` (thank [Tim Gilbert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1035840/what-is-the-equivalent-to-in-windows/1035848)) and I received 1. So it totally makes sense for me.

Even the command throws an error, we can still get the output in this case. You can refer to my code below:

```
const { execSync } = require('child_process')
console.log(process.env.ComSpec);// verify what terminal is used

try {

    // success command
    const resNpmVersion = execSync("npm -v");
    console.log("success", resNpmVersion.toString());

    // failed command, the result is printed in the catch block
    const resHelp = execSync("HELP");
} catch (error) {
    console.log(error.message);
    console.log("error", error.stdout.toString());
}
```

**Lesson learned**: Check the exit status of the command :)

(*I did my test on Windows 10*)